# Renaming files with spaces in the file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to rename something in bat including a space. when the command reads what after the space = the result of the rename. I want to order the bat to specific the name like " xx "
Example:

```
ren :OLDNAME:start_loading_01 - Copy.dds :NEWNAME:start_loading_02.dds
```

The name including space already so it's like

```
ren :OLDNAME:start_loading_01 :NEWNAME:- :NEWNAME Copy.dds
```

So the result comes: The syntax of the command is incorrect!

Any help?

Comment: Does this -- `"` -- exist on your keyboard?  If yes, make use of it.

Comment: What's with the `:OLDNAME:` and `:NEWNAME:`?

Comment: As @JamesL. said: what are the colons supposed to mean? They're not quoting characters. A colon in batch syntax indicates a label (destination for a `goto` instruction). A colon in a filename indicates an [alternate data stream](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs.aspx).

Comment: @Ansgar, I guess it's just their way of signalling a placeholder, just like I would use *«old name»* maybe.

Comment: @Јοеу Not a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

You have to quote paths with spaces

```
ren "old name" "new name with even more spaces"
```